# Find repeated entries in a column and index it with numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have a data table (say dt ) which has five columns  say ( A , B , C , D , E) all are string type  , now am including a 6th column F which nothing but concatenation of A+B+C+D.

why i am doing this ? because it servers as a unique key for every row.

Now some times it may happen that A+B+C+D  of one row will be equal to the same on another row. in which case i have to name this as A+B+C+D_1. by any chance if it comes again then _2.

**Now here is the tricky part ,**

this _1 ,_2 incremental logic is **not common** through out the table. it is based on the value of E column.

ie , in other words a value Say "Val1" may appear in 10 rows in the data table at column E. these 10 rows are a chunk for me. if needed , above mentioned index appending should happen only in this 10 values. and then the index/counter is reset.

lets say there are another 10 rows having value as "Val2" for column E .
now again i will make the unique key as mentioned above but any index appending should start again with "_1"

what i have tried till now ? As dt is already sorted / ordered by column E

```
for all unique value uv at column E in dt 
{
  temnpdt =  dt. select("E='uv'").copydatatable
     for all rows in tempdt
        { 
           make a string array of all A+B+C+D (Temp array)
        }
  
        **do something with this array and change the append the index where ever it is needed**
        //unsure how to do the above thing///
         
 }
```

Comment: Why go to all this effort?  Just add an auto inc integer field for your unique key

Comment: I have to agree with Hursey. Just use a surrogate key, e.g. an identity in SQL Server or an AutoNumber in Access. It is very rare that I use anything else for primary keys. You can always apply an index to those five columns if you want to speed up searching and any other logic can be applied at the point of query.

Comment: Looks like a strange mix of C# and vb.net.

Comment: .net provides a GUID. Globally Unique Identifier If you can't change the database table as commented above.

Comment: ok adding a flat integer at end may not be the good solution. coz the purpose of the integer is to just  not to make the unique key . 
when a unique key has say _3 then i would have to search the unique key 3 times in some other place. 
so there goes the importance

Comment: @seetharaman, ok well surrogate keys may not be the answer, still seems like your trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.  In some other place, wouldn't it be better to just query your data based on the combination of columns a,b,c,d,e etc?